# Why can't I make "onclick" event handler in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, onclick

It works when I put the "onclick" handler as an attribute. Like

```
<div class="myDiv" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com/'"></div>
```

But it doesn't work when I do it like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ... Around here has "title","meta" and "css link", then ...
    <script src="myEvent.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ... Any thing here ...
    <div class="myDiv"></div>
    ... Any thing here ...
  </body>
</html>
```

And "myEvent.js" looks like

```
var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv");
myDiv.onclick = function(){
  window.location = "http://www.google.com/
};
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` gets a nodeList, an array-like object containing multiple elements, and you have to iterate.

Comment: I also believe you have to include your external JavaScript file at the end of your HTML file (instead of in the head) in order for the div to actually exist. The browser loads the JavaScript before the rest of the body, and the JavaScript is run before the div is created in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your little comments. "GravityScore" 's name owner was right. And thank you "adeneo" but it doesn't solve my problem. It is not the right answer but it is my new knowlegde.